# Deep linking opens the app but does not open the exact url

Tags: java, android, android-webview, deep-linking

I have made a WebView app and deep linking works on it. Whenever someone clicks a link to my website (on any other app) then my app opens but, the homepage loads up instead of the URL clicked. I want the exact URL of my website to open whenever the link is clicked instead of the homepage.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.yoalfaaz.yoalfaaz;

        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
        import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
        import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;
        import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.webkit.WebSettings;
        import android.webkit.WebView;
        import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
        import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView YoWeb;
    private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;

    SwipeRefreshLayout swipe;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        YoWeb = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview); // Move your declaration up here
        swipe = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);
        swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                LoadWeb(YoWeb.getUrl());  // Pass in the current url to refresh
            }
        });

        LoadWeb("https://www.yoalfaaz.com");  // load the home page only once
    }

    public void LoadWeb(String url) // Pass in URL you want to load
    {

        WebSettings webSettings = YoWeb.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        YoWeb.loadUrl(url);  // Load the URL passed into the method
        swipe.setRefreshing(true);
        YoWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            //onPageFinished Method
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                //Hide the SwipeRefreshLayout
                swipe.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (YoWeb.canGoBack()) {
            YoWeb.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate menu resource file.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        // Locate MenuItem with ShareActionProvider
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);

        // Fetch and store ShareActionProvider
        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(item);

        // Return true to display menu
        return true;
    }

    // Call to update the share intent
    private void setShareIntent(Intent shareIntent) {
        if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
            mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
        }
    }

    //private Intent setShareIntent() {
    //    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    //    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    //    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
    //    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    //    startActivity(shareIntent);
    //    return shareIntent;
    //}
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.yoalfaaz.yoalfaaz">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:host="www.yoalfaaz.com" android:scheme="https"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

How to make it work as it works with most other apps? Like if we click on a YouTube link in WhatsApp then that particular video opens in YouTube app instead of YouTube homepage.

Comment: `LoadWeb("https://www.yoalfaaz.com");  // load the home page only once`. Well that opens your home page isnt it?

Comment: @greenapps Yes, it opens my homepage. It's made because every time I swipe to refresh on any web-page of my website, I ended on coming back to homepage.

Comment: `Whenever someone clicks a link to my website (on any other app) ` Which app? You mean some browser app?

Comment: Yes that is your home page url. So put the clicked url in it to land at that page.

Comment: @greenapps "Which App?" to be specific, I meant to say WhatsApp. If I click a link of my website on WhatsApp then it opens my website but not the exact URL.

Comment: Your app opens your home page. I see no code that does open another page. So what are you asking for?

Comment: @greenapps ok let me clear this, when I open my app generally then www.yoalfaaz.com should open (and it does open that). But if someone clicks a link of a web-page (eg: www.yoalfaaz.com/abc) in my website then, this web-page should open in the app instead of www.yoalfaaz.com.

Comment: Yes i understand. But i see no code at all that you try to acquire that url. If you do nothing -like you do now- you will open your default url.

Comment: @greenapps that's what I want to know, how to proceed in that direction. I have searched a lot but couldn't understand how it's done. Can you tell how to do it as the URL can be anything (eg: www.yoalfaaz.com/abc or www.yoalfaaz.com/xyz or www.yoalfaaz.com/mno) and that's what is confusing me.

Comment: Well think that you know the mechanism but forgot a bit.. Ok. Lets suppose you would launch another activity in your app. And you would transfer some data to that activity. Some parameters.  How would you do that? And where would the new activity extract that data from?

Comment: @greenapps I am really sorry but, I couldn't figure that out. I am still quite new to Android.

Comment: Then google for 'android how to start another activity'. There you see all. WhatsApp will have started your 'activity' in the same way using putExtra() for parameters. So use getIntent() and extract the parameter(s).

Comment: @greenapps thanks a lot, I'll search for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
LoadWeb("https://www.yoalfaaz.com");  // load the home page only once
```

Instead of hardcoding the URL, use `getIntent().getData().toString()` to get the URL(as a `string`) that is clicked from the other apps and use this URL to load web view.

Have a `null` check and load default URL if there is no URL received from `getData()`.

Hope this helps.

========= EDITED to show the code as you have asked =====================

In your code, you are loading web view with this line.

```
LoadWeb("https://www.yoalfaaz.com");  // load the home page only once
```

Modify this line like below.

```
String url = "https://www.yoalfaaz.com";
if(null != getIntent().getData()){
url = getIntent().getData().toString();
}
LoadWeb(url);
```

Comment: can you tell exactly how it should be coded to get the URL as a string and not doing this the way I am doing?

Comment: edited answer to show you code how to get the url. Have a look.

Comment: `getIntent().getData()` always returns `null` to me no matter what